# Maven reactor and transitive dependencies

Tags: java, maven

my projects have the following structure:

```
tst.parent
    with modules:
    tst.one
        -> has dependency to tst.two
    tst.two
        -> has dependency to tst.three
    tst.three
```

the goal is to have two builds. the first is a full build and the second only builds module tst.one and tst.three.
for this reason i made two profiles in the pom.xml of tst.parent:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>tst</groupId>
    <artifactId>tst.parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>tst.parent</name>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>part</id>
            <modules>
                <module>tst.one</module>
                <module>tst.three</module>
            </modules>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>full</id>
            <modules>
                <module>tst.one</module>
                <module>tst.two</module>
                <module>tst.three</module>
            </modules>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

the pom.xml of module tst.one:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>tst.parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>tst</groupId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>tst.one</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>tst</groupId>
            <artifactId>tst.two</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

the pom.xml of module tst.two:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>tst.parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>tst</groupId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>tst.two</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>tst</groupId>
            <artifactId>tst.three</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

the pom.xml of module tst.three:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>tst.parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>tst</groupId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>tst.three</artifactId>

</project>
```

if i run a full build, the reactor is sorting/building the modules in correct order:

```
mvn clean install -P full
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO]
[INFO] tst.parent
[INFO] tst.three
[INFO] tst.two
[INFO] tst.one
```

but if i run a partial build, the modules are sorted like i list them in the modules section:

```
mvn clean install -P part
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO]
[INFO] tst.parent
[INFO] tst.one
[INFO] tst.three
[INFO]
```

if i use the --project commandline-option, the buildorder is calculated correctly:

```
mvn clean install -P full --projects tst.one,tst.three
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO]
[INFO] tst.three
[INFO] tst.one
[INFO]
```

but with this approach, there is the limitation, that module tst.two must be available as source as well.

does anyone have an idea how to tell maven that in the partial build, the transitive dependency from module tst.one to module tst.three should be considered while calculating the reactor buildorder?
or
how i can tell maven to ignore the missing module tst.two as source and resolve this module from the repository for the --project approach?

Comment: What would you like to achieve with this? Apart from that never use profiles in relationship [with modules](http://blog.soebes.de/blog/2013/11/09/why-is-it-bad-to-activate-slash-deactive-modules-by-profiles-in-maven/).

Comment: i would like to have a system that is buildable, even if some modules belonging to that parent aren't available as source in a specific branch.

Comment: Such multi module build should be within the same structure and checked-in in the same are of version control...so i don't see any problem with that...